# TimedRotatingFileHandler not working for minute intervals

Tags: python, logging

I have configured a couple of TimedRotatingFileHandlers like this.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile, logfile_errors

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile, logfile_errors

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
args=('./logs/log.out','S', 1, 10)
formatter=logfileformatter

[handler_logfile_errors]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=ERROR
args=('./logs/errors/log.out','M', 1, 10)
formatter=logfileformatter
```

However, when I log something like this in different minutes

```
logging.error('MY ERROR')
```

Backup files (1 per second) are created for the logfile handler but not for the logfile_errors handler (I would expect one backup file per minute in which an error was logged). Am I doing something wrong when configuring the handlers?

Comment: It appears the two handlers log to a different path. Are you sure `logs/errors/` exists and is writeable?

Comment: @blues yes, if I switch the M for S between them, the S one is always the correct one.

Comment: Given this is all in the standard library, what exact version of python are you using?

Comment: @N1ngu I'm using 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any error in your config... it works on my machine :-)

Here is a minimal working example so you can check on your side, using your config without any modification:

```
import logging
import logging.config

import time


logging.config.fileConfig('mytestlog.conf')

while True:

  logging.error('other error message')
  time.sleep(0.5);
```

Resulting files after running about 3 minutes:

```
$ ls logs | sort
errors
log.out
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-20
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-21
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-22
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-23
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-24
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-25
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-26
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-27
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-28
log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-29


$ ls logs/errors/ | sort
log.out
log.out.2022-02-09_09-51
log.out.2022-02-09_09-52
```

Sample contents:

```
$ cat logs/log.out.2022-02-09_09-54-20 
2022-02-09 09:54:20,109 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:54:20,610 root        : ERROR other error message


$ cat logs/errors/log.out.2022-02-09_09-52 
2022-02-09 09:52:54,367 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:54,869 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:55,370 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:55,872 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:56,373 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:56,875 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:52:57,376 root        : ERROR other error message
..
..
2022-02-09 09:53:52,536 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:53:53,037 root        : ERROR other error message
2022-02-09 09:53:53,540 root        : ERROR other error message
```